# Haskell: Calculate differences of every pair of adjacent elements in a list

Tags: list, haskell

I have a function (mergeall) that returns a float list. I want to calculate differences of every pair of adjacent elements in this list. For example:

```
[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6]
do 1.1-2.2, 2.2-3.3,3.3-4.4...
return list of all difference
```

So, this should be pass into a list and return a list. The problems are:

1. How can I use the list from "mergeall"?
2. How can I do the algorithm above?
   Could somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
differences fs = zipWith (-) fs (tail fs)
```

Comment: Or the pointfree version: `differences = ap (zipWith (-)) tail`

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.` instead of `ap` since no lifting into a monad is involve? Also, `.` has a lower precedence than function application.

Comment: @JeffBurdges Actually, some lifting is involved -- in particular, into the `(e ->)` monad. Function composition `(.)` doesn't quite cut it here, because the same argument is supplied twice in different places.

Comment: @augustss: That's why I supplied it as a comment instead of as part of the answer proper. I find it interesting to see the pointfree versions of various functions, but they are often more obtuse.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want the opposite difference (e.g. `2.2-1.1`), the pointfree version would look like `zipWith (-) =<< tail`

Comment: Ahh, `ap = liftM2 ($)` here lifts function application to the second argument for its first argument `zipWith (-)` but doesn't mess with `tail` and the monad dictates that all functions apply to the same value.  cute.  :)

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Yeah, it took me a while to wrap around how the `(e ->)` monad worked. I still find it faster to ask the [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) utility to generate these expressions for me, but at least now I can read them pretty easily.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: Which is why `zipWith subtract =<< tail` gets you back to the "original" version.

Answer (score 2):

A pointfree solution using `Control.Applicative`:

```
differences = zipWith (-) <*> tail
```

Editor's note: I don't understand why this post is deleted by the owner. It's a good answer.