# Haskell nested lists

Tags: haskell, nested-lists

I'm new to haskell programming and I'm trying to check if the diagonally adjacent elements in the nested lists are not negative of each other.
I have my function as:

```
checkNegation :: [[Int]] -> Bool
```

Example: `checkNegation[[1,2], [3, -1]]` will return `False`
`checkNegation [[1,2],[-1,3]]` will return `True`.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: "I have my function as" - that's not an actual function, that's the type of your function, a declaration of the function. What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest breaking the problem into steps.

Step 1: Write a function to get the diagonal elements:

```
diag :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3998891/7203016) helpful.

Step 2: You'd like to check if the adjacent elements of the resulting list are negatives of each other:

```
allAdjNeg :: [Int] -> Bool
```

where `allAdjNeg [-1,1,-1,1] = True`.

This, too, might be most easily done in steps.  In step 2(a), check each pair of adjacent elements.  You may be able to adapt the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409022/haskell-calculate-differences-of-every-pair-of-adjacent-elements-in-a-list) to write a function:

```
adjNeg :: [Int] -> [Bool]
```

Hint:  If you define a function `isNeg x y = x == -y`, this is a binary operator just like `(-)` and can be used with `zipWith` in the same way.

In step 2(b), you want to see if the list `[Bool]` returned by `adjNeg` is all-True.  The `and :: [Bool] -> Bool` function will be helpful here.  That should allow you to define `allAdjNeg`.

Then, your final function will be something like:

```
checkNegation :: [[Int]] -> Bool
checkNegation lsts = not (allAdjNeg (diag lsts))
```

Comment: I don't want only the diagonal elements. It should include all the diagonally adjacent elements. Like for a rectangular list, index 0,1 will b adjacent to 1,2 and 1,0

Comment: FYI I've posted a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798643/testing-diagonally-adjacent-elements-in-nested-lists) including the OP's clarifications. Made the new post because it invalidates this answer somewhat.

Comment: @AditiJain: can you make a fair attempt and edit your question with specific questions about why that attempt is not working?

Comment: @AditiJain if you do come up with some code and have questions about it, please post a new question, including a link to this one for background; please do not make edits that would invalidate existing answer(s).