# haskell - detect diagonally adjacent elements

Tags: haskell, nested-lists

The objective of the function is to take a board in the form of a list of lists of `Square`s and returns `True` if no `Square` contains a white where there is a green square diagonally adjacent to it in the following row.

The function signature is:

```
diagchecker :: [[Square]] -> Bool
```

Square is defined as:

```
data Square = White | Green | Empty deriving Eq
```

For example, `diagchecker [[White,Empty],[Empty,Green]]` should return `False`.

`diagchecker [[Green,Empty],[Empty,White]]` should return `True`.

`diagchecker [[White,Green],[White,White],[Green,Empty]]` should return `False`.

---------Update------------

OK I'm basically one step away from getting this right.
Here is my code:

```
data Square = White | Green | Empty deriving Eq

diagchecker :: [[Square]] -> Bool

anyDiags :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> Bool
anyDiags p = fst . foldr f (False, [])
  where
    f xs (a, ys) = ( a || or (zipWith p xs (drop 1 ys)) 
                       || or (zipWith p (drop 1 xs) ys)
                   , xs)

greenAfterWhite x y = (x == White && y == Green)
    
diagchecker = anyDiags greenAfterWhite
```

This code actually works, and now the only problem I'm facing is that I want `diagchecker` to return `True` when there is no green after white, and return `False` when there *is* green after white. Under current situation it is doing the job detecting whether there is green after white, but the result Boolean it returns is exactly the opposite of what I want. Can anyone please help me with this?

-----Update No.2-----

For changing the output I've tried changing `greenAfterWhite` like this:

```
greenAfterWhite x y 
    | (x == white && y == green) = False
    | otherwise = True
```

or this:

```
greenAfterWhite x y = not (x == White && y == Green)
```

Both of these changes all result in the `diagchecker` returns `TRUE` for every single input `[[Square]]`.

Comment: I recommend starting with [a tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials). Once you have enough knowledge to try, do; when you get to a point where you feel you cannot make progress, then you will have a question we'll be excited about answering. Show us the code you've arrived at and tell us why you think it's not possible to fix whatever problem it has, and we'll help you over that bump. (Right now the way to make progress is obvious -- educate yourself -- so there's nothing for us to help you with.)

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a homework service. Make a fair attempt and come back
with *specific* questions about that attempt. See the
[*open letter to students with homework problems*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Hey guys I made a lot of progress. Is there anyone actually still interested in giving me a hand?

Comment: @DanielWagner Would you please help reopening the question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would you please help reopening the question?

Comment: related: [Testing diagonally adjacent elements in nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798643/testing-diagonally-adjacent-elements-in-nested-lists)

Comment: For transforming one `Bool` to another, [Hoogle's got your back.](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Bool%20-%3E%20Bool)

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried that already but wherever I put not in the code, it isn't working.

Comment: @WillNess Greetings to the original poster! I actually learnt from the highest score answer to write this, but while his code is simple and elegant it actually has the same problem: the boolean returned is always the opposite of what the question wants, and wherever I tried adding 'not' in the code, it isn't working.

Comment: I've shown my attempts to solve the problem in Update No.2. Please check it out.

Comment: I just posted someone else's question there. :) will look into yours when I have some time; meantime I've voted to reopen this one...

Comment: naming is important. `diagchecker = noGreenUnderWhiteDiagonally ; noGreenUnderWhiteDiagonally rows = null [ () | (a:b:_) <- tails rows, greenUnderWhite a (drop 1 b) || greenUnderWhite (drop 1 a) b] ; greenUnderWhite a b = or $ zipWith (...) a b`.

Comment: @WillNess So you are not using the 'anyDiags' predicate here anymore? And since now the question is reopened, would you mind writing this into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only check the two diagonal squares *below*, I'll express this as a mapping on tails. You're welcome to reformulate it in terms of `foldr`:

```
import Data.List (tails)

diagchecker = noGreenUnderWhiteDiagonally

noGreenUnderWhiteDiagonally rows = 
  null [ ()
         | (a:b:_) <- tails rows,
           greenUnderWhite a (drop 1 b) 
           || 
           greenUnderWhite (drop 1 a) b]

greenUnderWhite row1 row2 = 
  or $ zipWith (...) ... ...
```

You will need to complete the definition to check the presence of green square underneath in case the  square above is white.

`or` will detect whether any `True` element is present in its argument list.

The negation is already built into the code, with `null` detecting whether its argument list is empty. The elements of that list are not important, so we use the "bland" value, `()`.

The mapping on `tails` achieves *pairwise* comparison of consecutive rows in your matrix.